# how to run python file again and again in ubuntu?

Tags: cron

I am new to ubuntu .

I have a python file . i just want to execute it in every 15 min .

any body can tell, how i can do it ?

with all basic steps

Thank you

Comment: Is this meant to be running always and every time you boot -> cron job, or only if you start a script (BASH: `while sleep 15 ; do python file.py ; done`)

Comment: run when sytem is running

Comment: @Fiximan that's seconds.

Comment: @Oli - Oh lost the `m` while typing, should have been: `sleep 15m`